# Shanghai - a city of China & fraud, Is it a coincidence?

Tags: word-difference

According to Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary:

> to trick or force sb into doing sth that they do not really want to do

Also according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghaiing):

> Shanghaiing or crimping is the practice of kidnapping people to serve as sailors by coercive techniques such as trickery, intimidation, or violence. Those engaged in this form of kidnapping were known as crimps.

I find it funny and curiousity at the same time when Shanghai is also a city of China, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghai):

> Shanghai (Chinese: 上海; Mandarin: [ʂâŋ.xài] (About this sound listen); About this sound Wu pronunciation) is one of the four direct-controlled municipalities of China

So Shanghai means a city of China & fraud, Is it a coincidence?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. A quality dictionary should supply you with the etymology of the verb *[shanghai](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shanghai)*, which indeed relates to a common destination for kidnapped sailors in the 19th century. It is not a commentary on the city of Shanghai itself.

Comment: @choster: Thanks for your comment, so you mean it is a coincidence?

Comment: Even the verb "shanghai" doesn't mean "fraud". I think you should look up the meaning of "fraud" because they're not the same. They have similar notes but different central concepts.

Comment: @Catija: Good point, but I want to find a word that short and capture the concept of `shanghai (verb)`, If I use the word `trick`, I think it will mislead people into `playful trick`. while the word `fraud` clearly mean: `wrongful or criminal deception intended to result in financial or personal gain.` I think the important keyword here is `personal gain` (I google for `fraud definition` and google gives me this definition)

Comment: The word that captures the concept is "to kidnap".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a coincidence; however any derived meaning of "coerce" is based on the practice of *crimping* mentioned in your second example.

> **[shanghai (v.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/shanghai)**: "to drug a man unconscious and ship him as a sailor," 1854, American English, from the practice of kidnapping to fill the crews of ships making extended voyages, **such as to the Chinese seaport of Shanghai**.

Which is to say, the verb came into use not because the people of Shanghai would do this, but because that is where these sailors might end up by the time they were able to leave ship, i.e. *on the other side of the world*.

Over time the colorful expression came to be used for any scheme that involves even moderate coercion:

> Mary somehow **shanghaied** the other students into her crazy scheme to paint the school mascot bright yellow before the big game.  I'm surprised they didn't all get arrested.

Answer (score -2):

As a proper name it always starts with a capital letter - **Shanghai**, whereas as a verb it doesn't - **to shanghai**.

The dictionaries give you the right definitions. I hasten to add that the verb isn't very common nowadays.

Comment: but I'm still curious if it is a coincidence. Is it possible to find out the origin of the word Sanghai in case city of China & fraud.